# nested for loop giving no output when working with two lists

Tags: python, python-os, file-manipulation

I am making a file sorter in Python and I have two lists. One is called `downloads`, which holds the names of all of my files in my downloads directory, and the other is called `files`, which is intended to hold all of the needed information about each file so that I can make user interaction more simple. I am trying to bring all of the information from `downloads` into the `name` value of each `download_files` object. Whenever I run the code, it does not output anything, and it does not give any sort of error message.

```py
class download_files:
    def __init__(self, name, type):
        self.name = name
        self.age = type

import os

a = 0
b = 0
downloads = os.listdir(r"C:\Users\crazy\Downloads\\")
files = []

def main():
    for a in downloads:
        for b in files:
            b = download_files(a, 0)
            print()

main()
```

Comment: `for b in files:` when `files = []` (empty) does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
a = 0  # unused value
b = 0  # unused value
downloads = os.listdir(r"C:\Users\crazy\Downloads\\")
files = []

def main():
    for a in downloads:
        for b in files:  # iteration over empty list
            b = download_files(a, 0)
            print()

main()
```

you want to do something more like:

```
downloads = os.listdir(r"C:\Users\crazy\Downloads\\")
files = [download_files(name, 0) for name in downloads]
```

i.e. build `files` out of `download_files` objects built out of the elements of `downloads`, rather than creating an empty `files` and then trying to loop over it.

Note: a better name for your `download_files` might be something like `DownloadFile` -- it's a single file (right?), and classes usually get `CamelCase` names in Python to distinguish them from instances and functions (which get `snake_case` names).